# How to show mini controller of exoplayer at bottom of each activity or fragment?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm working on podcast player and i user exoplayer to play audio so I wanna
have mini controller at all of page like every app like castbox , ...
when you press back from player page the mini player show at other page in bottom and when click on it the player activity will open and resume play
I found one image that show you what I mean
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hi it's pretty easy you need to design it using a fragment the mini player would be fragment and would dispatch a backpress event with activity that triggers your required event

Comment: This sounds very interesting, do you have an example?